# How Can I run Tomcat again

Tags: tomcat, war

When I develop a web application.I delete `.idea` file.Then I reimport the project.I have `.idea` again.
But I can't run Tomcat 9;I lose my war file.I think I need a new war file.
So I build a new war.But the output layout is different from a web application.Although I  can run Tomcat 9.But I can not get access to any resource.It gives me a 404 error.How can I fix this.Thanks!
[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Is this about the missing war file?  Or the 404 issue or Tomcat not running?

Comment: I just want to run Tomcat again.I delete `.idea` file and import project again.